# Translation of a mathematical statement formulated in words to one formulated in predicate logic

Tags: logic, transformation, logic-translation

I want to express the fact that for all $x \in A$ that have the property that for all $y\in x$ $T(x,y)$ is true and there exists an $u \in B$ such that $P(y,u)$ is true AND for all $v\in C$, $Q(y,v)$ and $R(x,v)$ are also true, then $S(x)$ is true.

(Note that this statement is just a toy statement I have invented, because I was not sure I understood this transformation well, so I wanted to make it difficult, keeping with the idea, that if I got this difficult one right, that I probably understood how to do the transformations)

Formulated in a formal language of predicate logic, would this be

$$ \forall x ( x\in A \land \ \ \forall y (y\in x \rightarrow \ ( T(x,y) \land \ldots  $$
$$ \ldots \land ( \exists u ( u \in 
B \land P(y,u) \land \forall v ( v\in C \rightarrow ( Q(y,v) \land R(x,v)))))))\rightarrow S(x) ) $$

(hope I didn't forget any paranthesis...) 
?

Is there also a way to move the quantifiers "$\forall$" at the front, so that that string starts with $\forall x \forall y \ldots$ ?

Comment: All quantifiers can be moved to the front. However, we cannot in general move the universal quantifiers to the front, to be followed by the existential quantifiers. (I am assuming that we will not introduce additional function symbols to the language.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As André said, you can move all of the quantifiers to the front; the result is an expression in what is called [prenex normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form), and the conversion can be done quite mechanically. A formula can have more than one prenex normal form, but they will of course all be logically equivalent.

**Edit:** As Carl reminded me, logically equivalent prenex forms *can* (contrary to what I originally wrote) begin with different quantifiers: $\forall x \exists y(\phi(x) \land \psi(y))$ and $\exists y \forall x (\phi(x) \land \psi(y))$ are both prenex forms of $\forall x \phi(x) \land \exists x \psi(x)$. However, the order of the quantifiers can also matter: $\forall x \exists y \phi(x,y)$ and $\exists y \forall x \phi(y,x)$ are not logically equivalent. And it is certainly not possible in general to bring all of the universal quantifiers to the front.

Comment: Before marking your answer as the correct one: So the transformation from the formulation in english to predicate logic language was correct ?

Comment: @temo: Yes (unless I miscounted parentheses). However, since $u$ doesn’t appear after ‘AND’, it might be more natural to write $\dots \land (\exists u(u\in B \land P(y,u)) \land \dots \land R(x,v))))))\to S(x))$, limiting the scope of $\exists u$ to $u\in B \land P(y,u)$.

Comment: It isn't true that all the prenex normal forms must have the same classification, e.g. $(\forall x) P \land (\exists y) Q$ can be put in either $\forall \exists$ or $\exists \forall$ form.

Comment: @Carl: You’re absolutely right; I’ve no idea what I was thinking (if indeed I was!). Corrected.

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott ok, thanks, good remark about the scope of $u$